# Add Animation to my 3d model in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I am a problem which I don't think it is hard to solve but did not solve yet, I think I am missing something, Well I had a character with an animation (running animation) and other character with an other animation that works fine on my model, I want that my player jump and return to his running animation after that when  I click my button up...

I have two animations:

[image]

I have created my animatorController:

[image]

I added my character to the scene and attached the AnimatorController to it of course, I created a script (the code is inside my script):

```
private Animator animator;

private void Start () {
    // Position left and right
    obj = GetComponent<Transform> ();
    posCenter = obj.position.x;
    // used for Jump anim
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void Update () {
    obj = GetComponent<Transform> ();

    if (Swipe() == "up"){
        //transform.Translate (Vector3.back * (speed * Time.deltaTime),Space.Self);
        animator.Play("Jump");
    }
```

For the Character running animation, its duration is 32 and the Jump animation is 23, but When I click my model I have this :

[image]

I didnt know how to add the animation here... I think I have a problem here but I am not sure if it is the only problem, Well I clicked on the ' + ' button but it did not work...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe using `animator.Play("")` will make it play that animation until you tell it to play a different animation and it won't rely on the state machine you created in your animator.  If you click on the white arrows in your animator you can set conditions for the animation to transition to a new animation automatically, and you can set those conditions using `animator.SetBool("Jump", true)`.

Comment: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-sub-state-machine-hierarchies?playlist=17099